# Changing DATE format for selected column

Tags: c#

I have modified a little bit of code by coding as shown below. Can you please let me know after that?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Date_Format df = new Date_Format();
            df.cmbColumns.DataSource = cmbList;
            df.ShowDialog();

            //string str=DateTime.
            CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en - US");
            String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sszzz";
            DateTime parsedBack = DateTime.ParseExact(str, format, en.DateTimeFormat);
}
```

ERROR: The name 'str' doesn't exist in the current context. Please let me know the correction i have to do.

Comment: It should be `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:tt`. You are asking it to parse the month twice.

Comment: "and it's giving error on this line" - sorry, left my mindreading hat at home, would you mind including the error?

Comment: Error is: FormatExceptionwasnhandled

Additional Information: Input string is not in a correct format

Comment: `String.Format` is a function, i.e. it returns a value. Anyway, what you probably should be doing is described in [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Format` uses the syntax `{0}`, `{1}` etc for placeholders. Optionally, you can pass further formatting information by separating the placeholder's index from the formatting with a colon.

eg,

```
String.Format("{0:F2}",123.456) // format number to 2dp
```

in your case:

```
var result = String.Format("{0:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:tt'}",data)
// do something with result
```

However, `data` MUST be an instance of `DateTime` for this to work - in your code this is a string!

Lastly, `String.Format` returns a new string formatted appropriately, so having that on its own on a line makes little sense - it'll do nothing.

Comment: Yeah i added the line you suggested but this time i'm not getting any error but there is no change in datagridview (DATES are as is. Not changing).

Comment: This is my code:

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Date_Format df = new Date_Format();
df.cmbColumns.DataSource = cmbList;
df.ShowDialog();

string data = "";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
data = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Sent Date"].Value); 
var result = String.Format("{0:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:tt'}", data);
}

Comment: @Aditya I cant read code in a comment - thats not what they're for. If you have an update of your code, update the question. (Saying that - you're still not doing anything with `result` and `data` is still a string - did you actually read my answer?)

Comment: Hi, I have modified a little bit of code by coding as shown below. Can you please let me know after that? 
CODE: 
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
Date_Format df = new Date_Format(); 
df.cmbColumns.DataSource = cmbList; 
df.ShowDialog(); CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en - US"); 
String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sszzz"; 
DateTime parsedBack = DateTime.ParseExact(str, format, en.DateTimeFormat); 

ERROR: str does not exist in the current context.